# Can I set position of richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I want to set the position of richtextbox by take position of mouse at present.
I already know how to take mouse position. But I don't know how to set the position of richtextbox. Of course, position of richtextbox with desktop not with form.

I tried location, it didn't work.
Expected result:

[image]

Comment: You can use `richtextBox1.Location = location;` but it's unclear what `location` do you expect. *It didn't work* doesn't help us to help you. What the image is trying to describe? And what the code you used to do the job?

Comment: Do you just want the textbox to follow the mouse?

Comment: The picture mean that. After I get text (hello) , I will show the richtextbox that have the meaning of hello. I want to show it next to the mouse. Of course the mouse can move everywhere, not in form.

Comment: Ok, so now I just want to ask, can the ricthextbox move out the form.? The first question, I did succesfully . But it's only move with mouse when form appear. If the form disappear only mouse have, richtextbox disappear

Comment: Why don't you use a tooltip?

Comment: If you want to show extra information on a control on mouse over, the tooltip is exactly what you need.

Comment: I already think about this. But It's not what I want. I'm making a dictionary that have function search on others application.
Example:
When I choose "hello" text on the PDF file, it will show for me what it mean immediately, I don't need to look up in dictionary

Comment: I actually tried reproducing your problem making the richtextbox show up on mouse over and at mouse position, but it's really not necessary.

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a, text;
            a = Clipboard.GetText();
            text = a.ToLower();
            for (int i = 0; i < cbbtu.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (cbbtu.Items[i].ToString() == text)
                {
                    cbbtu.SelectedIndex = i;
                    rtbnghia2.Visible=true;
                    rtbnghia2.Text = rtbnghia.Text;
                    rtbnghia2.Location = MousePosition;                 
                }
            }
        }

Comment: It's not work on the others application, only work in form

Comment: You can set the text to the tooltip as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will try one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional form without borders with RichTextBox placed on it. And change form position by timer.

Simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer timer;
        Form form;
        RichTextBox richTextBox;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            form = new Form
            {
                Size = new Size(50, 20),
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
                TopMost = true,
                ShowInTaskbar = false
            };
            richTextBox = new RichTextBox { Parent = form, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            timer = new Timer { Interval = 10, Enabled = true };

            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            form.Show();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X + 10, MousePosition.Y - 20);
        }
    }
}
```